# Can I increase jdbc batch size in hibernate for development purposes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I want to update a column value in a table containing 800k rows. So, I have created a simple Java application with Hibernate **4.3.6.Final** as an ORM framework.

I have configured the JDBC batch with 45 as a value and I have disabled the use of second level cache.

```xml
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">45</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
```

Can I increase the `batch_size` for example to 200? Because in hibernate [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html) they mention:

> Before batch processing, enable JDBC batching. To enable JDBC batching, set the property hibernate.jdbc.batch_size to an integer between 10 and 50.

This is the code (simplified):

```java
session.beginTransaction();

List<MyEntity> entities = findAllEntities();
logger.info("Number of fetched rows: " + entities.size());

int count = 0;

for (MyEntity entity : entities) {

    // change some fields of the entity

    session.update(entity);

    if ( ++count % HIBERNATE_BACH_SIZE == 0 ) {
       //flush a batch of updates and release memory:
       session.flush();
       session.clear();
    }
}

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: I am doing an analysis with values of that column. So, every time I change in how to generate the value of that column I need to wait for 3h or so.

Comment: Can you share your code? In what fashion are you performing the update?

Comment: @Stultuske absolutely.

Comment: @akortex91 please check again, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetching all the entities and then looping through them one by one is quite tedious and will always result in suboptimal performance.

Since it seems that you perform an unconditional update (i.e no checks are in place to define which object will get its fields updated) you should use a simple `HQL` query to perform the update in a single action.

For example, given the table you want to update is `MyEntity` then your query would looke like this:

```
int rows = session.createQuery("UPDATE MyEntity ME SET me.myField1=:newField1, me.myField2=:newField2)
     .setString("newField1", "Something")
     .setString("newField2", "Something")
     .executeUpdate();
```

Using that should improve performance a lot.

Comment: Having done a bunch of performance improvements / mitigations on corporate software mis-using ORM frameworks over the last decade -- this advice right here gets modded up.

However, the only thing I'd add is to use the appropriate query language for the project you're working in. 

If you're using hibernate-jpa, use JPQL. Otherwise, HQL.

You _can_ certainly change property definitions between environments, that becomes a configuration matter -- and you should have a means of changing configuration parameters without requiring a recompile / rebuild of your app. That's a different issue.

Comment: @bvarner Very true what you mention, but given the limited details the OP provided it would have hard to guess what they are in fact using. The basic idea behind the answer was to steer him towards the correct direction, which is to avoid using an ORM for what we was trying to achieve.